# Debugging injected JavaScript with Firebug

Tags: debugging, firebug

Is there a way to debug (set breakpoints, follow code step-by-step etc.) JavaScript code that was dynamically added via AJAX? I can't find it, seems like it only allows to review inline JS (main page source) and in external .js files.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to debug dynamically evaluated scripts, because the Firefox debugger APIs Firebug is based on don't give access to them yet.

Though there's already a [bug report at Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865313) asking for these APIs.

There's also a [simple test case for eval()ed scripts](http://www.softwareishard.com/firebug/jsd2/tests/eval/eval.html) on Jan 'Honza' Odvarko's website.

Edit:
Debugging dynamically evaluated scripts *is* possible. The only thing you have to take care of is that you choose the right evaluated script. E.g. when you click the "Eval!" button of the test case twice, you'll see two evaluated scripts inside the [Script Location Menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Location_Menu), but just the latter is debuggable.

Sebastian

Comment: That bug is about JSD2, no? I think JSD1 ought to have debuggable eval() code.

Comment: You're right. It's possible with some restrictions. I updated my answer to reflect that.